# Oracle most repeating value and count

Tags: sql, oracle

Please could you help how can I create query based on the following source data and result?
(primarily without subquery)

Source data:

```
Item        | Quantity
Crankshaft  | 200
Crankshaft  | 100
Crankshaft  | 200
Crankshaft  | 50
Crankshaft  | 200
Gear        | 400
Gear        | 200
Gear        | 300
Gear        | 400
Housing     | 120
Housing     | 50
Housing     | 50
```

Result:

```
Item        | Most Frequent Quantity    | Count
Crankshaft  | 200                       | 3
Gear        | 400                       | 2
Housing     | 50                        | 2
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about ties? What do you want to show if, for a given Item, there are two (or more) quantities tied for "most frequent quantity" (for that Item)?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select item, quantity, cnt
from (select item, quantity, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by item, quantity
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution combining count aggregate function and row_number analytic function.

```sql
select ITEM, QUANTITY, CNT
from (
select Item, Quantity, count(*)cnt
    , row_number()over(partition  by Item order by count(*) desc)rnb
from t
group by Item, Quantity
)
where RNB = 1
order by ITEM
;
```

Comment: Note about your `order by` clause: since you select only one row for each distinct `item`, there will never be ties when you order by `item` alone. So, the `cnt desc` is not needed - it will never actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to extract is called *mode* in statistics. Oracle has built in aggregate function for this: [`stats_mode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STATS_MODE.html#GUID-10BDACE0-C435-4E3F-BC50-FD1A41C0F508). However, I do not know the function, which may return a count for mode in one pass. And built in function and below solutions do not take care of ties. I cannot come up with the solution without a subquery for ties

The easiest way is to do `distinct` over analytic function to get the desired result without subquery:

> ```
> select distinct
>   item,
>   max(quantity)
>     keep(dense_rank first
>     order by count(*) desc
>   ) over(partition by item)
>     as quantity_mode,
>   max(count(*))
>     over(partition by item)
>     as mode_count
> from t
> group by item, quantity
> ```
>
> ```
> ITEM       | QUANTITY_MODE | MODE_COUNT
> :--------- | ------------: | ---------:
> Crankshaft |           200 |          3
> Housing    |            50 |          2
> Gear       |           400 |          2
> ```

Or to do some tricks with all the values aggregated like count this value inside collection variable or via `xmlagg` and XQuery. Whatever you want depending on the reason you want to avoid subquery.

One possible way is to count the number of occurrences in `listagg` result. Below I use a percent sign as a delimiter for both the sides to allow count of exact tokens regardless of their relative position (not to resolve the issue when one delimiter needs to be counted twice in consequent items). To avoid `varchar2` limitation you may use [`max_string_size = extended`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm) in 12c+ or apply the same logic to `xmlagg(...).getclobval()` result with appropriate change in regex.

> ```
> select
>   item,
>   stats_mode(quantity) as quantity_mode,
>   regexp_count(
>     listagg (
>       '%' || to_char(quantity, 'TM9') || '%')
>       within group (order by 1)
>   
>     , '%' ||
>       to_char(stats_mode(quantity), 'TM9')
>       || '%'
>   ) as mode_cnt
> from t
> group by item
> ```
>
> ```
> ITEM       | QUANTITY_MODE | MODE_CNT
> :--------- | ------------: | -------:
> Crankshaft |           200 |        3
> Gear       |           400 |        2
> Housing    |            50 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25e8f3e7661169ec40c5fdb4ec7bca5e)*